# Error while trying to download Image URL from Firebase database using Swift3

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

Would you please help me to find the error in my code? I have an image URL in my database and I'm trying to download it and display it in a TableView, but it shows nil value.

This is my Class:

```
class Post : NSObject {

  var Posts : String!

  var Image : String!


}
```

and this is My TableView.

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import SDWebImage


 class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var MyImageView: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var Ref:FIRDatabaseReference?

var Handle:FIRDatabaseHandle?

var myarray = [Post]()



   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {


    Ref=FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    Handle = Ref?.child("Posts").observe(.childAdded ,with: { (snapshot) in

        let post = snapshot.value as? Post

            self.myarray.append(post!)

            self.tableView.reloadData()

    })


    }


   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}


   public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

return myarray.count

}


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if   let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as? TableViewCell {

  //      cell?.textLabel?.text = PostData[indexPath.row]

        let url = URL(string : self.myarray [(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].Image!)

        cell.MyImage.sd_setImage(with: url)

        return cell

    }else{

        let cell = TableViewCell()

        let url = URL(string : self.myarray [(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].Image!)

        cell.MyImage.sd_setImage(with: url)


       return cell


    }

  }



 }
```

Comment: first, did you check the url value with the debugger?

Comment: Yes it's appears nil

Comment: and myArray at the row is not nil? show the value here please. (an invalid url will return nil)

Comment: does the table myArray have the data for the rows at the end of viewDidAppear?